# PHP Converting number into non standard format

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have a game I am working on and am storing the amount of money as a single number instead of pieces of gold, silver and copper.

E.g PlayerX has 123 gold, 45 silver and 67 copper
In this instance the database entry would store 1234567 as the money value. 100 copper = 1 silver and 100 silver = 1 gold

Is there an easy way to convert the long number into gold, silver and copper values easily?

Comment: Will you ***never*** want to know how much silver or copper a player has? Because if you ever do, you should simply store these separately. You should really ask yourself, ***"what advantage do I gain by combining them to justify the increased complexity that arises from doing so?"***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%`:

```
$copper = $money % 100;
$silver = floor( ( $money % 10000 ) / 100 );
$gold = floor( $money / 10000 );
```